# in python, how can I match a part of a string to another string, but not trigger a false positive with this example:

Tags: string, matching

In python, I need to compare `testString` to `stringA` to `stringB`, but not trigger a false positive with `stringC`, but still trigger a match to `stringA`.  Please see the example below:

```
testString = "Ft"

stringA = "Ft"
stringB = "FtLtTp
```

Do I need to use regular expressions? the "is in" technique returns true for both string examples. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I should elaborate... I can't just use an == operator, as I do need it to return a match in other circumstances such as, when Ft is compared to Ft_camera, but not true against FtLtTop_camera.

Comment: Where's stringC?

Comment: You need to set up a regular expression with characters that can be used to catch the provided `testString`.  Your parameters for this aren't clear, but it sounds like want to capture i.e. 'Ft' where it is not followed by another alphabet character.  So, you'll need to figure what you want to match the expression on.

Comment: Thank, that helps. And my bad Shawn, stringC was not really important, it was just going to be filler, to pad out the test situation.  I am collecting a list of cameras in a scene, and iterating through that list and comparing it against a list of render layers, and if they match, I run some commands. But its tripping up right now and giving me false positives where the names might include the shorter name, but still not be a true match... I have not used reg expressions much, so maybe this is an example where I need to learn?